# nvcc dynamic exception specifications are deprecated

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I'm getting

> warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated

when compiling with nvcc after upgrading to CUDA 9.2. I am using gcc 8.1, which is not officially supported.

The offending file is

> /usr/local/cuda/include/crt/common_functions.h

Is there any way to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 2):

If you add

> -Xcudafe --display_error_number

to the nvcc command, it will generate a warning number. That warning number (without the symbols or letters) can then be used in the offending code to suppress the warning:

```
#pragma push
#pragma diag_suppress 2381

<offending lines>

#pragma pop
```

or on the command line as

> -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=2381